# C# If loop within a for loop within an if loop

Tags: c#, if-statement

I would like to reduce this code if I can:

```
class Alarm
{
    internal static void isGreaterThanOrBelowValue(int min, int max, int now, int i)
    {
        MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();

        if (now < min && now !=0)
        {
            if(i == 1)
            {
                mw.TxtBox1.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            }
            if (i == 2)
            {
                mw.TxtBox2.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            }
            if (i == 3)
            {
                mw.TxtBox3.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            }
        }
        if (now > max && now !=0)
        {
            if(i == 1)
            {
                mw.TxtBox1.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            }
            if (i == 2)
            {
                mw.TxtBox2.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            }
            if (i == 3)
            {
                mw.TxtBox3.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            }
        }

}
```

I want to do the following:

i can be between 1 and 33.

I can get the textbox name (TxtBox1) etc.

I would like to reduce the if statements so I don't have 32 if statements for each larger if statement.

Thank you! :)

Comment: `if` statements are not loops. They simply execute depending on the condition presented.

Comment: What is the question? Even the Description is incoherent

Comment: Refactor into methods

Comment: Cleaning up this code is a great idea! You have magic numbers, violate the DRY principle ... Suggestion: put all textboxes into an array and then access the array with index `i`.

Comment: The question is, can I condense the if statements down? @GlorinOakenfoot I have a for loop that calls this method, each time giving incrementing i by one 32 times. It does the for loop every 2 seconds on a timer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use an array for the textboxes, something like this:

```
internal static void isGreaterThanOrBelowValue(int min, int max, int now, int i)
{
    MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
    TextBox[] tbList = new TextBox[] { mw.TxtBox1, mw.TxtBox2, mw.TxtBox3 };

    if (now !=0 && (now < min || now > max))
    {
        tbList[i-1].Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    }
}
```

You could also build the array outside the function as a class member if the textboxes don't change, so that you were not rebuilding it every time the function is called:

```
static MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
static TextBox[] tbList = new TextBox[] { mw.TxtBox1, mw.TxtBox2, mw.TxtBox3 };

internal static void isGreaterThanOrBelowValue(int min, int max, int now, int i)
{
    if (now !=0 && (now < min || now > max))
    {
        tbList[i-1].Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, for one you can do this:

`if ((now < min || now > max) && now !=0)`

Which simplifies your statements dramatically, as both `now<min` and `now>max` do the same thing.

For the 33 text boxes, you'd have to either put them into an array and use an index lookup, write a function called `getTextBoxFromIndex()` and do the giant-if-block once, or see if you can do something like `mw["TxtBox"+i]` (some environments will support it, others wont).

Answer (score 0):

For one you can reduce the code by using "else if" instead of "if" everytime.

When you do

```
if(I==1)
{
}
if(I==2)
{
}
```

It will check both conditions always.

When you do

```
if(I==1)
{
}
else if(I==2)
{
}
```

The second statement will only be checked if the first statement is false. Since we know i=1, we know i can't be 2, so we shouldn't check statement 2.

Also read the comments because they give good information. You can write a function that checks if i>0 and i<3 and sets the brush to red accordingly. Honestly this question is too broad. There are many ways to reduce your code.